# What is the replacement for EXEC sp_dboption <dbname> in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012

From [microsoft connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/723806/sql-server-2012-rc0-missing-master-sys-sp-dboption-stored-procedure) you learn, that it is closed by design. But they do not tell how to replace

```
EXEC sp_dboption master
```

to query the current db options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the options are in [`sys.databases`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx)

Comment: Yes that works for me. SQL-Server 2005, 2008, 2012